# Boost set default edge weight to one

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use Boost's graph algorithms (djikstra, bfs etc) and I want the edge weights to be one by default, without having to set them every time I add edges. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use a weigh_map of [`static_property_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/property_map/doc/static_property_map.html):

> This property map wraps a copy of some particular object, and returns a copy of that object whenever a key object is input.
>
> ```
> template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
>     static_property_map<KeyType, ValueType>
>     make_static_property_map(const ValueType& value);
> ```

So `boost::make_static_property_map(1)` would be enough to use as weight 
map argument to either of those algorithms.

In case you want default values, with *possible* exceptions, use e.g. [`function_property_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/property_map/doc/function_property_map.html) to do the evaluation.